# How to draw random lines with CSS to replicate effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm not sure what to call this effect or even how to look it up. I want to do something similar. Hover over the links on the navigation bar and you'll see what I'm talking about.

http://www.bleedingthrough.com/

[EDIT] To clarify. It's a hover effect where random lines appear to be drawn over the links in the navigation menu. How would I go about making a similar effect?

[EDIT] How do I replicate this effect by drawing lines over the words using CSS, HTML5, and/or Javascript?

Comment: It certainly is Flash. Just a hint, but if you see an element, or an element with a style, you'd like to replicate: right-click it and select 'inspect element' (assuming an up-to-date browser). If it turns out to be a Flash movie, then at least you'll know.

Comment: Flash? Uggh, that explains the lag. @DavidThomas I'll do that. I normally do, but didn't.

[EDit] Right clicking proves flash.

Comment: For something similar with jQuery/CSS3, you can look into CSS animations and draw random lines within the bounding box of the words you're hovering over.  You can break the word up into as many 10px wide rectangles as will fit, for example. Then for each rectangle, draw a line from a random point on one half of the top edge to a random point on the other half of the bottom edge.  Then draw one or two horizontal lines using the same principle.

Comment: @Milimetric I'll look into that for the CSS3 transitions and how to draw a line, but I think a GIF could do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done through flash. If you right click on the menu you can see it. But It's possible to do somewhat similar with HTML/CSS/CSS3. Also JavaScript framework like jQuery will be helpful to you.

Few EG:

http://designshack.net/articles/css/5-cool-css-hover-effects-you-can-copy-and-paste/

Comment: Do you have any idea how? Could using an animated gif work, or would there be a better way to replicate it? Thanks for the site. It has some cool stuff on there.

Comment: easiest way to do is using a GIF. Otherwise you will have to manually write the animation using jQuery or somewhat similar

Answer (score 0):

In addition to an animated GIF, you could get something similar with some reasonably simple CSS. Create a background image then apply this to your nav links on hover.

Admittedly it doesn't have the fade-in effect, but it's simple, low bandwidth and will work well on mobile.

http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/Lm3MF/

**CSS**

```
a:hover, a:active{
background: url("path-to-your-background.gif") 
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I can also use JQuery to give it a fade in effect.